# how i can put the watermark at the center position of the image?

Tags: python, image, automation, python-imaging-library, watermark

i have 10k images so i'm trying to put the watermark on all the images using Pillow library but watermark position always change as you can see in below images.

i want to put the watermark at the center position of every image and watermark should not be too large and too small from the image, it should be perfect for every image so could you please tell me how i can do it?

this is watermark image:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

i'm using this code:

```
from PIL import Image
import glob


def watermark_with_transparency(input_image_path, output_image_path, watermark_image_path, position):
    base_image = Image.open(input_image_path) #open base image
    watermark = Image.open(watermark_image_path) #open water mark
    width, height = base_image.size #getting size of image

    transparent = Image.new('RGBA', (width, height), (0,0,0,0))
    transparent.paste(base_image, (0,0))
    transparent.paste(watermark, position, mask=watermark)
    #transparent.show()
    transparent.convert('RGB').save(output_image_path)
    print 'Image Done..!'



for inputImage in glob.glob('images/*.jpg'):
    output = inputImage.replace('images\\','')
    outputImage = 'watermark images\\'+str(output)

    watermark_with_transparency(inputImage, outputImage, 'watermark.png', position=(0,0)) #function
```

Comment: You've been given `position=(0,0)`. You need to calculate tha center of image, and adjust size of your watermark to the desired aspect ratio with original image.

Comment: what are the resolutions of the images and the watermark image?

Comment: @vishes_shell could you please tell me how i can calculate the center of image?

Comment: @FlyingTeller every image has different resolutions and that's the main problem. i attached watermark image also. you can check it out now

Comment: @RashidAziz i bet there is ton of answers how to place new image on top of another at the center. Google it, and SO answer will appear!:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best option is to resize the watermark like this:

```
base_image = Image.open(input_image_path) #open base image
watermark = Image.open(watermark_image_path) #open water mark
watermark = watermark.resize(base_image.size)
```

Comment: but how i can put it into the center position of every image?

Comment: Don't need to specify position if both images are the same size.

Comment: Since the watermark is in the center of the watermark image, it should end up in the center of the overlayed image if you don't specify position

Comment: there are 10k images and all images size and resolution are not same so regarding this problem i think we have to locate the center point of the image

Comment: not if you resize your watermark every time to have the same resolution than your image. That also makes the watermark the same size in every image

Comment: I don't believe that best option is to resize watermark, since it will be stretched...

Comment: Depends on how much the aspect ratio of images vary from that of the watermark. But from the example images it is clear that resolutions greatly differ, so "Sample" might not even fit onto the image without resizing. Therefore some resizing should be done. Wether or not to conserve the aspect ratio depends on the context

Answer (score 11):

You are passing the position as 0,0. If you want it be centered then you should update the position from within the function by dividing the width and height of image by 2 and subtracting the width and height of watermark divided by 2 from it.

```
X coordinate = width_of_image/2 - width_of_watermark/2

Y coordinate = height_of_image/2 - height_of_watermark/2
```

[image: sample]

Here's an example code:

```
width_of_watermark , height_of_watermark = watermark.size
position = ((width/2-width_of_watermark/2),(height/2-height_of_watermark/2))
```